# How to add extra CSS when an image is uploaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I upload an image, I want the text box to stay completely inside the grey area. Right now when I upload an image, the text box is not completely inside the grey area. Is there any way I can automatically expand the grey area where the text box is in when an image is uploaded? Thanks!

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ppilot2/02bn8pzh/)
https://jsfiddle.net/Ppilot2/02bn8pzh/

```js
let cssProps = {
  'font-weight': '',
  'font-style': '',
  'text-decoration': ''
}

$('input[name="textStyle"]').change(function() {
  const val = $(this).val()
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    switch (val) {
      case 'bold':
        cssProps['font-weight'] = 'bold';
        break;
      case 'italic':
        cssProps['font-style'] = 'italic';
        break;
      case 'underline':
        cssProps['text-decoration'] = 'underline';
        break;
    }
  } else {
    switch (val) {
      case 'bold':
        cssProps['font-weight'] = '';
        break;
      case 'italic':
        cssProps['font-style'] = '';
        break;
      case 'underline':
        cssProps['text-decoration'] = '';
        break;

    }
  }
  $('textarea[name="styledText"]').css(cssProps)
});
var loadFile = function(event) {
   var image = document.getElementById('output');
   image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `load` event listener, and use it to add a class that you can then apply styling to:

```js
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  image.classList.add('loaded');
});
```

Here's an example:

```js
const url = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/02/23/33/annas-hummingbird-6146187_960_720.jpg';
const image = document.getElementById('image');
image.addEventListener('load', () => {
  image.classList.add('loaded');
})
image.src = url;
```

```css
img.loaded {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<img id='image' width='200'/>
```